# How can I host a website on another domain without sacrificing SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, godaddy, 302-redirect

I have a domain bought at Godaddy, but I do not have a hosting service there. Rather, I have a subdomain on another site that I control, and forward it using a 302 temporary redirect. However, I have found that this sacrifices SEO of my new domain in favor of the location that it is hosted at.

Is there a way to allow the new domain to reap the SEO benefits on Google, rather than the one it's hosted at?

Comment: Instead of using a redirect why don't you just set the nameservers to that of your actual host and then setup your hosting to work with this domain as well.

Answer (score 2):

As im aware **best practice is to `301` redirect**. (`.htaccess` allows for "wilcard" redirects.)

[stackoverflow.com -  How can I use htaccess to redirect paths with a wildcard character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877486/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-redirect-paths-with-a-wildcard-character)

> Google has a guide named [Transfer, move, or migrate your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/6029673?hl=en&ref_topic=6001951)
>
> If you've moved your site to a new domain or subdomain, use the Change
>   of address tool in Search Console.
>   [Google webmasters - change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)

Additionally: moz.com also has a [SEO Guide: How to Properly Move Domains](https://moz.com/blog/seo-guide-how-to-properly-move-domains) but its from 2009, similar info anyways.